# Coreutils timeout(1) plays badly with man/less

Tags: terminal, process-management, timeout

I want to set a timeout to the `less(1)` command on our company's production server. Everyday we produce large log files on it, and despite the nightly batch job to archive/remove them, we sometimes get alerted on high disk usage because a (long-)running process can prevent a file from getting `unlink(2)`-ed physically due to the reference-counting semantics of POSIX filesystems.

To avoid the most common cases of such annoyances, I wrote a wrapper of `less` which runs it under [`timeout(1)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) so that idle `less` processes get automatically killed after several hours without keeping open files in the filesystem.

But it turned out to play badly with `man(1)`: when the wrapper is launched by the `man` command via the `PAGER` environment variable, it stopped responding to any keyboard inputs. Here is a minimal reproducible test case:

```
$ PAGER='timeout 12h /bin/less' man man
```

After running this, `ps fx` output looks like this:

```
19415 pts/1    SNs    0:00  \_ -bash
19854 pts/1    SN+    0:00      \_ man man
19867 pts/1    SN     0:00          \_ timeout 12h /bin/less
19869 pts/1    TN     0:00              \_ /bin/less
```

and I could only `kill -KILL 19869` to regain an access to the terminal.

What did I get wrong here?
Why is the `less` process in the `T` state, as opposed to `S`?

Comment: Show us the wrapper please

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if I temporarily put `man`/`less` in the background through `Ctrl+Z`. Did you do that to run your `ps` command?  That _would_ put `less` in a T state...  Using `timeout` in `PAGER` seems to work as expected on my OpenBSD system.

Comment: I suspect that the less process is getting suspended because it isn' in the foreground (so it receives SIGTTIN when it tries to read from stdin). @Kusalananda

Comment: @Gilles Had you given a comment a bit earlier... I just posted my findings as a solution to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Answering to my own question, as I couldn't really find any hints on this via my googling.

`strace(1)` could actually reveal that `SIGTTOU` had been sent to the `less` process.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html

> This is similar to `SIGTTIN`, but is generated when a process in a background job attempts to write to the terminal or set its modes. ...snip...

And apparently `timeout(1)` by default puts the process under management into background:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html

> `--foreground`
>
> Don’t create a separate background program group, so that the managed command can use the foreground TTY normally. ...snip...

So the solution to my problem was

```
$ PAGER='/bin/timeout --foreground 12h /bin/less' man man
```

(and something equivalent in my wrapper)

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder it seemed to be working on my system then?

Comment: @Kusalananda `/usr/bin/man` is a completely different beast on OpenBSD than on linux, especially since they got rid of groff.

Comment: `less` still doesn't work right with `timeout`; when killed by a signal, `less` will fail to restore the stty/termios settings, and you will be left with having to do a blind `reset` or `stty sane`; try `timeout 2s less ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @mosvy this (minimal example) wrapper seems to fix it for me `g=$(stty -g); timeout 2s less ~/.bashrc || stty "$g"`

Comment: Nodakai, on my Debian version of `timeout` the man page and effect appear to contradict the [GNU info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) you referenced. With `timeout 12h less` the page works as I would expect - until the timeout gets reached. Specifically, the `--foreground` option is _not_ required unless `timeout` itself is not being run directly from a terminal.